# Vitest workspace run all projects

Tags: vitest

I have this `vitest.workspace.ts` in the root directory of a monorepo:

```js
export default defineWorkspace([
  {
    test: {
      name: 'jsdom',
      environment: 'jsdom',
      include: ['**/*.jsdom.spec.{ts,tsx}'],
      globals: true
    }
  },
  {
    test: {
      name: 'node',
      environment: 'node',
      include: ['**/*.node.spec.ts'],
      globals: true
    }
  },
  {
    test: {
      name: 'e2e',
      environment: 'jsdom',
      include: ['**/*.e2e.spec.{ts,tsx}'],
      globals: true,
      globalSetup: ['./vitest.globalSetup.ts'],
      setupFiles: ['./vitest.setup.ts'],
      poolOptions: {
        threads: {
          singleThread: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I want to be able to run all of the 3 projects at once (in watchmode). Running each of the projects on its own works just fine. E.g

```bash
$ npx vitest --project=e2e
```

but if I run this

```
$ npx vitest --project=e2e --project=node --project=jsdom
```

I get an error `Expected a single value for option "--project <name>", received ["node", "jsdom", "e2e"]`. The documentation mentions that

```
The name of the project to run if you are using Vitest
workspace feature. 
This can be repeated for multiple projects: 
--project=1 --project=2
```

I am using vitest 1.3.0